# Caffe Net.Forward Error trying face detection with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, caffe, dotnetnuke

I'm getting into neural networks and tried some example code from this page [Link](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/FaceDetectionComparison/face_detection_opencv_dnn.cpp)

Everything works fine until I get to the part

```
cv::Mat detection = net.forward("detection_out");
```

- I'm using a RGB image as an input but also tried every CV_Type.
- I've tried different Config/Weight-Files. (I'm using the provided files [Link](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/FaceDetectionComparison/models))

Maybe some important code parts:

```
Scalar meanVal = Scalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0);
const size_t inWidth = 300;
const size_t inHeight = 300;
const double inScaleFactor = 1.0;
const float confidenceThreshold = 0.7;

#define CAFFE
    const std::string caffeConfigFile = "./deploy.prototxt";
    const std::string caffeWeightFile = "./res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel";

,..
,..
,..

Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(image, inScaleFactor, cv::Size(inWidth, inHeight), meanVal, false, false, 5);
net.setInput(inputBlob, "data");
cv::Mat detection = net.forward("detection_out");

,.. 
,..
,..

int main(){

Mat image(YRes, XRes, CV_32F, PixelPointerOut);
.............................
```

I get the following error message:

```
{msg="OpenCV(4.0.1-dev) C:\\OpenCV\\opencv-master\\modules\\dnn\\src\\layers\\convolution_layer.cpp:267: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Number of input channels should be multiple of 3 but got 1 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes"}
```

Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: 1. Try with empty layer name: cv::Mat detection = net.forward(cv::String()); 
 2. With Mat image(YRes, XRes, CV_8UC3... is the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying CV_8UC3 already solved it without using an empty layer name.
I was sure I tried it before because CV_32FC3 didn't work.
Thanks a lot!